eliminar etiquetas nodos de xml desde php
cordial saludo, solicito su ayuda para la siguiente situación, debo eliminar estas etiquetas/nodos, que estan dentro de una estructura xml. voy a explicar por partes como he venido realizando la pruebas, al inicio trato de hacer la estructura mas corta que es como se muestra y al final a adjunto toda la estructura xml de donde debo eliminar los registros incluidos dentro de InvoiceDocumentReference
   <cbc:ID schemeName="MZ3" schemeURI="http://www.dian.gov.co/contratos/facturaelectronica/v1/anexo_v1_0.html#MZ3">MZ3321686</cbc:ID>
<cbc:CopyIndicator>true</cbc:CopyIndicator>
<cbc:UUID schemeName="MZ3" schemeURI="v1/anexo_v1_0.html#MZ3" />
<cbc:IssueDate>2023-06-16</cbc:IssueDate>
<cbc:DocumentType languageID="es">Transcripción de factura de venta expedida manualmente en la fecha anotada en este fragmento, motivada en la ocurrencia de: ()</cbc:DocumentType>

las anteriores etiquetas estan dentro de un nodo llamado cac:InvoiceDocumentReference </cac:InvoiceDocumentReference>
entiendo que cac - cbc hacen parte del namaspace por ellos en el siguiente codigo los elimino. he intentado con el siguiente codigo de elimininarlas
$xmlString = <<<XML
       <InvoiceDocumentReference>
         <ID schemeName="MZ3" schemeURI="http://www.dian.gov.co/contratos/facturaelectronica/v1/anexo_v1_0.html#MZ3">MZ3321686</ID>
        <CopyIndicator>true</CopyIndicator>
        <UUID schemeName="MZ3" schemeURI="v1_0.html#MZ3" />
       <IssueDate>2023-06-16</IssueDate>
       <DocumentType languageID="es">Transcripción de factura de venta expedida manualmente en la fecha anotada en este fragmento, motivada en la ocurrencia de: () 
       </DocumentType>
       </InvoiceDocumentReference>
       XML;

      $dom = new DOMDocument();
      $dom->loadXML($xmlString);

      $invoiceDocRef = $dom->getElementsByTagName('InvoiceDocumentReference')->item(0);

      if ($invoiceDocRef !== null) {
       echo " entre";
          // Eliminar el contenido de los nodos hijos
       foreach ($invoiceDocRef->childNodes as $child) {
         $invoiceDocRef->removeChild($child);
        }
     }
     else{ echo "no entre ";}

    $filePath = 'C:/FTP/archivo_nuevo1.xml'; // Ruta y nombre del archivo nuevo
    $dom->save($filePath);

pero no he podido que me elimine las etiquetas, de antemano gracias
adjunto todo la estructura xml
<cac:Attachment>
<cac:ExternalReference>
    <cbc:MimeCode>text/xml</cbc:MimeCode>
    <cbc:EncodingCode>UTF-8</cbc:EncodingCode>
    <cbc:Description><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"          
     xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2" xmlns:ipt="pt:co:facturaelectronica:InteroperabilidadPT-2-1" xmlns:sts="dian:gov:co:facturaelectronica:Structures-2-1" xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" xmlns:xades141="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.4.1#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2 http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/os-UBL-2.1/xsd/maindoc/UBL-Invoice-2.1.xsd"><ext:UBLExtensions><ext:UBLExtension><ext:ExtensionContent><NotificationPreferences><NotifyPreferences><NotifyPreference><NotificationType>Mail</NotificationType><Destinations><Destination><Tos><To>Recepcion.fe</To></Tos><Tos><To>co</To></Tos><Tos><To>Hector</To></Tos></Destination></Destinations></NotifyPreference></NotifyPreferences></NotificationPreferences></ext:ExtensionContent></ext:UBLExtension><ext:UBLExtension><ext:ExtensionContent><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="xmldsig-422c0e40">
   <ds:SignedInfo>
   <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR" />
   <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
   <ds:Reference Id="xmldsig-422c0e40-69" URI="">
   <ds:Transforms>
   <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
   </ds:Transforms>
   <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
   <ds:DigestValue>YhBzV8YE=</ds:DigestValue>
   </ds:Reference>
   <ds:Reference URI="#xmldsig-14ebd8o">
   <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
   <ds:DigestValue>Holhw3zfcaFs=</ds:DigestValue>
   </ds:Reference>
   <ds:Reference Type="http://uri.etsi.org/01903#SignedProperties" URI="#xmldsig-422c0e40-6945-42ce-bff2-14ebd887264c-signedprops">
   <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
   <ds:DigestValue>MP7BMzeLTnOOQnSyg=</ds:DigestValue>
   </ds:Reference>
   </ds:SignedInfo>
   <ds:SignatureValue Id="ykju
   </ds:SignatureValue>
   <ds:KeyInfo Id="xmldsig-422c-keyinfo">
   <ds:X509Data>
   <ds:X509Certificate>
    4ZrzwwBcZw==
   </ds:X509Certificate>
   </ds:X509Data>
   </ds:KeyInfo>
   <ds:Object><xades:QualifyingProperties xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org#" xmlns:xades141="http://uri#" Target="#xmldsig-422c0e40-6945-42ce-bff2-14ebd887264c"> 
   <xades:SignedProperties Id="ps"><xades:SignedSignatureProperties> 
   <xades:SigningTime>2023-06-16T15:18:43.241+00:00</xades:SigningTime> 
   <xades:SigningCertificate><xades:Cert><xades:CertDigest><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" /><ds:DigestValue>88=</ds:DigestValue> 
   </xades:CertDigest><xades:IssuerSerial><ds:X509IssuerName>CN ECD Sub,O=,OU,1.2.840.113549.1.9.1=2d34</ds:X509IssuerName> 
   <ds:X509SerialNumber>9</ds:X509SerialNumber></xades:IssuerSerial></xades:Cert> 
   </xades:SigningCertificate><xades:SignaturePolicyIdentifier> 
   <xades:SignaturePolicyId><xades:SigPolicyId> 
   <xades:Identifier>v2.pdf</xades:Identifier><xades:Description>bia. 
   </xades:Description></xades:SigPolicyId><xades:SigPolicyHash><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="" /><ds:DigestValue>Y=</ds:DigestValue></xades:SigPolicyHash> 
  </xades:SignaturePolicyId></xades:SignaturePolicyIdentifier><xades:SignerRole> 
  <xades:ClaimedRoles><xades:ClaimedRole>supplier</xades:ClaimedRole> 
  </xades:ClaimedRoles></xades:SignerRole></xades:SignedSignatureProperties> 
  </xades:SignedProperties></xades:QualifyingProperties></ds:Object>
  </ds:Signature></ext:ExtensionContent></ext:UBLExtension><ext:UBLExtension> 
  <ext:ExtensionContent><sts:DianExtensions><sts:InvoiceControl> 
  <sts:InvoiceAuthorization>6</sts:InvoiceAuthorization><sts:AuthorizationPeriod> 
  <cbc:StartDate>4</cbc:StartDate><cbc:EndDate>4</cbc:EndDate> 
  </sts:AuthorizationPeriod><sts:AuthorizedInvoices><sts:Prefix>MZ3</sts:Prefix> 
  <sts:From>6</sts:From><sts:To></sts:To></sts:AuthorizedInvoices></sts:InvoiceControl> 
  <sts:InvoiceSource><cbc:IdentificationCode listAgencyID="6" listAgencyName="" listSchemeURI="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:codelist:gc:CountryIdentificationCode-2.1">CO</cbc:IdentificationCode></sts:InvoiceSource><sts:SoftwareProvider><sts:ProviderID schemeID="7" schemeName="31" schemeAgencyID="195" schemeAgencyName="CO">741</sts:ProviderID><sts:SoftwareID schemeAgencyID="1" schemeAgencyName="CO">7</sts:SoftwareID></sts:SoftwareProvider><sts:SoftwareSecurityCode schemeAgencyID="1" schemeAgencyName="CO)">0</sts:SoftwareSecurityCode><sts:AuthorizationProvider><sts:AuthorizationProviderID schemeID="" schemeName="" schemeAgencyID="" schemeAgencyName="CO">8</sts:AuthorizationProviderID> 
  </sts:AuthorizationProvider><sts:QRCode></sts:QRCode></sts:Diaons> 
  </ext:ExtensionContent></ext:UBLExtension><ext:UBLExtension><ext:ExtensionContent> 
  <CustomFieldExtension><CustomFieldExtension Name="TotalRetencion" Value="0" /> 
  <CustomFieldExtension Name="TelefonoEmisor" Value="" /><CustomFieldExtension Name="TelefonoReceptor" Value="80" /><CustomFieldExtension Name="Vendedor" Value="03" /> 
  <CustomFieldExtension Name="TelefonoVendedor" Value="" /><CustomFieldExtension Name="TipoCambio" Value="" /><CustomFieldExtension Name="NoReferecia" Value="MZ3" /> 
  <CustomFieldExtension Name="Condiciones" Value="35 Días" /><CustomFieldExtension Name="EmailCliente" Value="co;.co;co;" /><CustomFieldExtension Name="TelefonoCliente" Value="" /><CustomFieldExtension Name="MonedaFacturacion" Value="COP" /> 
  <CustomFieldExtension Name="Subtotal" Value="198180" /><CustomFieldExtension Name="Descuento" Value="0" /><CustomFieldExtension Name="Iva" Value="0" /> 
  <CustomFieldExtension Name="Impoconsumo" Value="0" /><CustomFieldExtension Name="Total" Value="198180" /><CustomFieldExtension Name="ValorTotalDocumento" Value="198180" /><CustomFieldExtension Name="ValorLetras" Value="CIENTO NOVENTA Y OCHO MIL CIENTO OCHENTA PESOS COLOMBIANOS" /></CustomFieldExtension></ext:ExtensionContent> 
  </ext:UBLExtension></ext:UBLExtensions><cbc:UBLVersionID>UBL 2.1</cbc:UBLVersionID> 
  <cbc:CustomizationID>12</cbc:CustomizationID><cbc:ProfileID>Venta</cbc:ProfileID> 
  <cbc:ProfileExecutionID>1</cbc:ProfileExecutionID><cbc:ID schemeID="3"></cbc:ID> 
  <cbc:UUID schemeID="1" schemeName="CUFE-SHA384">5</cbc:UUID><cbc:IssueDate>2023-06-16</cbc:IssueDate><cbc:IssueTime>15:16:00-05:00</cbc:IssueTime> 
  <cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>01</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode><cbc:Note>S.A.S  </cbc:Note> 
  <cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>COP</cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode> 
  <cbc:LineCountNumeric>1</cbc:LineCountNumeric><cac:OrderReference> 
  <cbc:ID>MZ321686</cbc:ID></cac:OrderReference><cac:BillingReference> 
  <cac:InvoiceDocumentReference><cbc:ID schemeName="3" schemeURI="3">6</cbc:ID> 
    <cbc:CopyIndicator>true</cbc:CopyIndicator><cbc:UUID schemeName="3" schemeURI="3" /><cbc:IssueDate>2023-06-16</cbc:IssueDate><cbc:DocumentType languageID="es">Transcripción de factura de venta expedida manualmente en la fecha anotada en este fragmento, motivada en la ocurrencia de: ()</cbc:DocumentType></cac:InvoiceDocumentReference> 
   </cac:BillingReference><cac:AccountingSupplierParty><cbc:AdditionalAccountID schemeAgencyID="195">1</cbc:AdditionalAccountID><cac:Party> 
  <cbc:IndustryClassificationCode>23</cbc:IndustryClassificationCode><cac:PartyName> 
  <cbc:Name>AS</cbc:Name></cac:PartyName><cac:PhysicalLocation><cac:Address> 
  <cbc:ID>101</cbc:ID><cbc:CityName>S</cbc:CityName> 
  <cbc:CountrySubentity>s</cbc:CountrySubentity> 
  <cbc:CountrySubentityCode>1</cbc:CountrySubentityCode><cac:AddressLine> 
  <cbc:Line>CR9</cbc:Line></cac:AddressLine><cac:Country> 
  <cbc:IdentificationCode>CO</cbc:IdentificationCode><cbc:Name languageID="es">CO</cbc:Name></cac:Country></cac:Address></cac:PhysicalLocation> 
  <cac:PartyTaxScheme><cbc:RegistrationName>S</cbc:RegistrationName><cbc:CompanyID schemeID="8" schemeName="1" schemeAgencyName="CO" schemeAgencyID="5">7</cbc:CompanyID> 
  <cbc:TaxLevelCode listName="No aplica">PN</cbc:TaxLevelCode><cac:RegistrationAddress> 
  <cbc:ID>01</cbc:ID><cbc:CityName>S</cbc:CityName> 
  <cbc:CountrySubentity>Caldas</cbc:CountrySubentity> 
  <cbc:CountrySubentityCode>17</cbc:CountrySubentityCode><cac:AddressLine> 
  <cbc:Line>C9</cbc:Line></cac:AddressLine><cac:Country> 
  <cbc:IdentificationCode>CO</cbc:IdentificationCode><cbc:Name languageID="es">A</cbc:Name></cac:Country></cac:RegistrationAddress><cac:TaxScheme> 
  <cbc:ID>01</cbc:ID><cbc:Name>IVA</cbc:Name></cac:TaxScheme></cac:PartyTaxScheme> 
  <cac:PartyLegalEntity><cbc:RegistrationName>S</cbc:RegistrationName><cbc:CompanyID schemeAgencyID="5" schemeAgencyName="CO" schemeID="8" schemeName="31">8</cbc:CompanyID> 
  <cac:CorporateRegistrationScheme><cbc:ID>3</cbc:ID><cbc:Name /> 
  </cac:CorporateRegistrationScheme></cac:PartyLegalEntity><cac:Contact> 
  <cbc:Name>x</cbc:Name><cbc:Telephone>3149</cbc:Telephone> 
  <cbc:ElectronicMail>co</cbc:ElectronicMail></cac:Contact></cac:Party> 
  </cac:AccountingSupplierParty><cac:AccountingCustomerParty> 
  <cbc:AdditionalAccountID>1</cbc:AdditionalAccountID><cac:Party> 
  <cac:PartyIdentification><cbc:ID schemeAgencyID="1" schemeAgencyName="CO" schemeID="7" schemeName="31">8</cbc:ID></cac:PartyIdentification><cac:PartyName> 
  <cbc:Name>S.A.S</cbc:Name></cac:PartyName><cac:PhysicalLocation><cac:Address> 
  <cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID><cbc:CityName>s</cbc:CityName><cbc:PostalZone>13</cbc:PostalZone> 
  <cbc:CountrySubentity>s</cbc:CountrySubentity> 
  <cbc:CountrySubentityCode>1</cbc:CountrySubentityCode><cac:AddressLine> 
  <cbc:Line>ZA</cbc:Line></cac:AddressLine><cac:Country> 
  <cbc:IdentificationCode>CO</cbc:IdentificationCode><cbc:Name>COLOMBIA</cbc:Name> 
  </cac:Country></cac:Address></cac:PhysicalLocation><cac:PartyTaxScheme> 
  <cbc:RegistrationName>S.A.S</cbc:RegistrationName><cbc:CompanyID schemeAgencyID="195" schemeAgencyName="CO)" schemeID="7" schemeName="31">8</cbc:CompanyID><cbc:TaxLevelCode listName="No aplica">O-13</cbc:TaxLevelCode><cac:TaxScheme><cbc:ID>01</cbc:ID> 
  <cbc:Name>IVA</cbc:Name></cac:TaxScheme></cac:PartyTaxScheme><cac:PartyLegalEntity> 
  <cbc:RegistrationName>S.A.S</cbc:RegistrationName><cbc:CompanyID schemeAgencyID="5" schemeAgencyName="CO" schemeID="7" schemeName="31">8</cbc:CompanyID></cac:PartyLegalEntity> 
  <cac:Contact><cbc:ElectronicMail>co</cbc:ElectronicMail></cac:Contact></cac:Party> 
  </cac:AccountingCustomerParty><cac:Delivery><cbc:ActualDeliveryDate>2021-07-01</cbc:ActualDeliveryDate></cac:Delivery><cac:PaymentMeans><cbc:ID>2</cbc:ID> 
  <cbc:PaymentMeansCode>46</cbc:PaymentMeansCode><cbc:PaymentDueDate>2023-07-21</cbc:PaymentDueDate></cac:PaymentMeans><cac:LegalMonetaryTotal><cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="COP">198180.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount><cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount currencyID="COP">0.00</cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount><cbc:TaxInclusiveAmount currencyID="COP">198180.00</cbc:TaxInclusiveAmount><cbc:AllowanceTotalAmount currencyID="COP">0.00</cbc:AllowanceTotalAmount><cbc:ChargeTotalAmount currencyID="COP">0.00</cbc:ChargeTotalAmount><cbc:PrepaidAmount currencyID="COP">0.00</cbc:PrepaidAmount><cbc:PayableRoundingAmount currencyID="COP">0.00</cbc:PayableRoundingAmount><cbc:PayableAmount currencyID="COP">198180.00</cbc:PayableAmount></cac:LegalMonetaryTotal><cac:InvoiceLine> 
  <cbc:ID schemeID="0">1</cbc:ID><cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="94">1</cbc:InvoicedQuantity><cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="COP">198180.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount><cac:Item><cbc:Description /> 
  <cbc:PackSizeNumeric>0</cbc:PackSizeNumeric><cac:StandardItemIdentification><cbc:ID schemeID="001" /></cac:StandardItemIdentification><cac:AdditionalItemProperty> 
  <cbc:Name>ValorUnitarioItem</cbc:Name><cbc:Value>198180</cbc:Value> 
  </cac:AdditionalItemProperty><cac:AdditionalItemProperty> 
  <cbc:Name>ValorTotalItem</cbc:Name><cbc:Value>198180</cbc:Value> 
  </cac:AdditionalItemProperty><cac:AdditionalItemProperty><cbc:Name>01</cbc:Name> 
  <cbc:Value /></cac:AdditionalItemProperty><cac:AdditionalItemProperty> 
  <cbc:Name>02</cbc:Name><cbc:Value /></cac:AdditionalItemProperty> 
  <cac:AdditionalItemProperty><cbc:Name>03</cbc:Name><cbc:Value>0</cbc:Value> 
  <cbc:ValueQuantity>0</cbc:ValueQuantity></cac:AdditionalItemProperty></cac:Item> 
  <cac:Price><cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="COP">198180.00</cbc:PriceAmount> 
  <cbc:BaseQuantity unitCode="94">1</cbc:BaseQuantity></cac:Price></cac:InvoiceLine> 
  </Invoice>]]></cbc:Description>
    </cac:ExternalReference>
  </cac:Attachment>


La propiedad de sólo lectura childNodes es de tipo NodeList, el cual puede recorrerse de maneras distintas dependiendo de la versión de PHP, de tal manera que no siempre el foreach es la mejor opción. Una forma segura de recorrer una lista de nodos es usando su implementación antigüa:
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xmlString);

$invoiceDocRef = $dom->getElementsByTagName('InvoiceDocumentReference')->item(0);

$nl = $invoiceDocRef->childNodes;
for( $i=0; $i<$nl->length; $i++ ){
   $child = $nl->item($i);
   if( $child instanceof DomElement )
      $invoiceDocRef->removeChild( $child );
}


muchas gracias, me funciono realizando el proceso de esta forma

Los namespaces no se eliminan, si no, no hay nada que te diga que tu XML es válido. Si lo que quieres es leer los nodos del XML se hace así:
libxml_use_internal_errors(true); 
$xml="";
try{
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($strContenidoXML);
}catch(Exception $e){
    //aqui maneja el error
}
$noNodosRet =  count($xml->xpath("/cfdi:Comprobante/cfdi:Impuestos/cfdi:Retenciones/cfdi:Retencion"));//extrae el numero de nodos retencion
$arrayImporteRetV32 =$xml->xpath("/cfdi:Comprobante/cfdi:Impuestos/cfdi:Retenciones/cfdi:Retencion/@importe");//Xpath que saca los importes V32
$arrayImpuestoRetV32=$xml->xpath("/cfdi:Comprobante/cfdi:Impuestos/cfdi:Retenciones/cfdi:Retencion/@impuesto");//Xpath que saca los impuestos V32
for($i=0;$i<$noNodosRet;$i++){
    $valorImporteRet =  "".trim($arrayImporteRetV32[$i]->importe);
    $valorImpuestoRet =  "".trim($arrayImpuestoRetV32[$i]->impuesto);
}

